# Number Validator in Asp.Net (Not allowed to even input other than character)

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, visual-studio

i want to use some validator other than the common asp validator, i have almost 70 fields in an application, as it is a costing calculator, i want, its fields should not accept a character, like if we press any alphabetic or non numeric character, it should not be written in the field even, i dont want page refresh, i dont want to call onkeypress events on every text field, as it makes my app slower.

Thanks a lot
Atif

Comment: I recommend to use RegularExpressionValidator in this case. Otherwise with Ajax as said below will make the page size increase drastically.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to achieve this. One of them is to use a MaskedEdit:

http://www.asp.net/ajax/ajaxcontroltoolkit/samples/maskededit/maskededit.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Check the FilteredTextBox extension from the AjaxControlToolkit library: http://www.asp.net/ajax/ajaxcontroltoolkit/Samples/FilteredTextBox/FilteredTextBox.aspx

Comment: Mostly controls from the AjaxControlToolkit library don't fire postback so both of FilteredTextBox and MaskedEdit extenders check values on client. Actually those controls are not validators, rather them just prohibit to enter invalid values without error message.

Answer (score 0):

I would create a single js function for a customvalidator. You would need to set one time for all your textfields but you can set this single function in all your validators. this would be less work. just copy and paste.

Comment: But the function will be tricky to write because the character will already be in the TextBox when the validation function is called. How do you then remove it?

Comment: It's a classic validation. it shows the red validation message and the user has to change the value.